# Eclipse AbstractTextEditor not editable

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Im writing a Eclipse Plugin and for that i need a custom TextEditor.
The contents of the TextEditor are supposed to be text extracted from a custom xml structure. I have all the data extraction done, but now im struggling with the task of providing the text to my TextEditor. 
I can actually set some Text to be displayed and that all works, the problem is that i cant edit it. 
My Editor Code so far:

FooEditor:

```
package fooeditor.editor;

import org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor;

public class FooEditor extends AbstractTextEditor {

    public FooEditor() {
    super();
    setSourceViewerConfiguration(new FooSourceViewerConfiguration());
    setDocumentProvider(new FooDocumentProvider());

}

}
```

FooSourceViewerConfiguration:
    package fooeditor.editor;

```
import org.eclipse.jface.text.source.SourceViewerConfiguration;

public class FooSourceViewerConfiguration extends SourceViewerConfiguration     {

    public FooSourceViewerConfiguration() {

}



}
```

FooDocumentProvider:
    package fooeditor.editor;

```
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IStatus;
import org.eclipse.jface.operation.IRunnableContext;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.Document;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.IDocument;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.IDocumentPartitioner;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.rules.DefaultPartitioner;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.rules.FastPartitioner;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.source.IAnnotationModel;
import org.eclipse.ui.part.FileEditorInput;
import org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDocumentProvider;
import org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.IDocumentProvider;
import org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.IElementStateListener;

public class FooDocumentProvider extends AbstractDocumentProvider {

    IDocumentPartitioner partitioner;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public FooDocumentProvider() {
        super();
        partitioner = new FastPartitioner(new FooPartitionScanner(), null);
    }

    @Override
    protected IDocument createDocument(Object element) throws CoreException {
        if (element instanceof FileEditorInput) {
            IDocument document = new Document();
            document.set("hi");
            document.setDocumentPartitioner(partitioner);
            return document;

        } else {
            throw new CoreException(null);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected IAnnotationModel createAnnotationModel(Object element) throws CoreException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doSaveDocument(IProgressMonitor monitor, Object element, IDocument document, boolean overwrite)
        throws CoreException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    protected IRunnableContext getOperationRunner(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

FooPartitionScanner:
    package fooeditor.editor;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.eclipse.jface.text.rules.EndOfLineRule;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.rules.IPartitionTokenScanner;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.rules.IPredicateRule;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.rules.IToken;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.rules.RuleBasedPartitionScanner;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.rules.Token;

public class FooPartitionScanner extends RuleBasedPartitionScanner implements IPartitionTokenScanner {

    public FooPartitionScanner() {
        super();
        List rules = new ArrayList();

        IPredicateRule[] result = new IPredicateRule[rules.size()];
        rules.toArray(result);
        setPredicateRules(result);

    }

}
```

Comment: It is usual to extend `org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor`.. Extending `AbstractTextEditor` leaves out the large amount of code in `StatusTextEditor`, `AbstractDecoratedTextEditor` and `TextEditor`.

Comment: Okay, i tested `org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor` but still if i try to implement my own DocumentProvider, i get the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AbstractTextEditor` sets the text editable or not according to the the result of the `isEditable` method. The default code for this is:

```
@Override
public boolean isEditable() {
    IDocumentProvider provider= getDocumentProvider();
    if (provider instanceof IDocumentProviderExtension) {
        IDocumentProviderExtension extension= (IDocumentProviderExtension) provider;
        return extension.isModifiable(getEditorInput());
    }
    return false;
}
```

The `AbstractDocumentProvider` you are extending does implement `IDocumentProviderExtension` but the default implementation of `isModifiable` is:

```
@Override
public boolean isModifiable(Object element) {
    return false;
}
```

So you need to override this (or perhaps look at using `StorageDocumentProvider`).